# how to install symfony1.4 on a shared host

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

i am developing a site in symfony1.4 and doctorine. i am developing it on my local host by installing pear and using command line. And on my local host i am using wamp server. now i would like to upload it on a shared host. how to install it on a shared host.i am not much aware of symfony .Any one please help me
                                             thanks in advance

Comment: That really depends on your hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

I follows this steps:

1. add the symfony framework inside the folder `myproject/lib/vendor`. In `ProjectConfiguration` class change the `require_once` instruction in `require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';`. So the framework folder will be called simply `symfony` without version.
2. upload the project, with the project folder, inside the root that is the domain folder;
3. use the url rewriting, adding inside the `.htaccess` file, the below code to use urls like `mydomain.com/the-remainder-of-the-address` instead of `mydomain.com/myproject/web/the-remainder-of-the-address`:

> Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
>
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>
> ```
>  RewriteEngine On
>  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.mydomain\.com [NC]
>  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myproject/web/$1 [NC,L]
> ```
>
> </IfModule>

Also to let generate by routing rule through the function `link_to` (or `url_for`) urls like `mydomain.com/friendly-name.html` instead of `mydomain.com/myproject/web/friendly-name.html` it needs to add in `myappConfiguration` class this code:

```
    public function configure()
    {
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/myapp.php';
    }
```

Finally I suggest you to have a look at this useful deployment check list: [symfony-check.org](http://symfony-check.org/) to solve typical problems in deployment.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put symfony library in your project lib
2. Change project configuration class for include autoload class of  framework.